# Django-Haystack returns no results

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I using Haystack with elasticsearch  backend. 
When I do a query I get no results. 
What else can I try?
I'm really stuck.
Any help appreciated! :)

Here's my code

view.py

```
class ActressSearchView(SearchView):
    template = 'search/search.html'
    form_class = SearchForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ActressSearchView, self).get_queryset()
        q = queryset.order_by('name','release_date')
        return q

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ActressSearchView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

url.py

```
url(r'^search/?$', ActressSearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
```

search_indexes.py

```
class EnActressIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    en_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')

    def get_model(self):
         return EnActress
    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()


class EnMovielistIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    content_ID = indexes.CharField(model_attr='content_ID')
    release_date = indexes.CharField(model_attr='release_date')
    actress = indexes.CharField(model_attr='actress')
    label = indexes.CharField(model_attr='label')

    def get_model(self):
        return EnMovielist

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Comment: did you define search_indexes.py and actress_text.txt ?

Comment: @arcegk Yes. I did